# UITableviewCell display text for another cell when I scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, reuseidentifier

When I scroll my custom UITableviewCells get wrong content (another cell's text).  This happens randomly.  I tried clearing the cell but then I get some blanks cell.  My code is below.  Can anyone tell me what is happening.  I have read many articles from here and elsewhere that cell needs to be cleared but none worked for me as I am not really sure at what point you clear the data.  I even tried implementing prepareForReuse in my cell's class but no good.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.products count] == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        return cell;
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AvailableCustomerProductCell";

    AvailableCustomerProductTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell.buttonAdd.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.buttonAdd addTarget: self action: @selector(addToSelectedProduct:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    Product *prod = nil;
    if (theTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        prod = (Product *)[self.filteredProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        prod = (Product *)[self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    if (prod != nil) {
        cell.pNumber.text = prod.number;
        cell.description.text = prod.desc;

        if ([Common getProductPromotion:prod] != nil)  {
            cell.btnPromotionTag.hidden = NO;
            cell.btnPromotionTag.tag = indexPath.row;
            [cell.btnPromotionTag addTarget: self action: @selector(showPromotionDetails:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else{
            cell.btnPromotionTag.hidden = YES;
        }

        //Get the customer product price, first:
        //If if the product has a record in the productCustomerPrices list
        //if not get the price from the standard price.

        if (self.order.orderOrderCustomer != nil) {
            CustomerPrice *custPrice = [Common getPriceForCustomer:self.order.customerRef forProduct:prod.productId];

            if (custPrice != nil) {
                //get the customer price
                [cell.btnPrice setTitle:[Common getCurrencyFormattedStringFromFloat:[custPrice.price floatValue]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cell.btnPrice setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.01 green:0.65 blue:0.77 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.btnPrice.enabled = NO;
            }else{
                //get the standard price
                float price =[[Common  GetProductStandardPrice:prod.productStanddardPrices ByQuantity:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]] floatValue];
                [cell.btnPrice setTitle: [Common getCurrencyFormattedStringFromFloat:price] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
                [cell.btnPrice setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.39 blue:0.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.btnPrice.tag = indexPath.row;
                [cell.btnPrice addTarget: self action: @selector(showStandardPrices:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                cell.btnPrice.enabled = YES;
            }
        }
    }

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* sgr = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellSwiped:)];
    [sgr setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:sgr];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Which object's text isn't disappearing?

Comment: BTW you should add the gesture recognizer inside the cell subclass rather than in cellForRow

Comment: The target method is on the view controller.  It is too much hassle to call it from the cell as far as I know

Comment: You gesture recognizer could be added on a single cell multiple times

Comment: You are right.  Didn't think of that.  Will change it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is *almost certainly* related to the fact that table views **recycle cells**. That's the reason the cells need to be "cleared", as you put it.

For example, if you have one cell near the top that has an image being displayed, if you scroll further down and that same cell is used to display a cell that shouldn't have an image, that image will still appear unless you've removed it since. Even if you had 100 cells to display, there are probably only a handful of instances that actually exist - they get recycled.

That being said, even though you didn't say which text is still appearing, if `prod` is `nil`, it could be a variety of objects, including `pNumber` and `description`. Same goes for if `self.order.orderOrderCustomer` is `nil`. To avoid things like this, you can just put something like the following right after getting the `cell`:

```
cell.pNumber.tex = @"";
cell.description.text = @"";
//etc
```

Another note: You're adding a target to your cell's `buttonAdd` button. You should remove existing actions on the line before it. For example:

```
[cell.buttonAdd removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
[cell.buttonAdd addTarget: self action: @selector(addToSelectedProduct:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Same goes for `btnPromotionTag` and `btnPrice`.

Comment: I tried 
    [cell.btnPrice setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
right after cell dequeue it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What text is still appearing? Is it `cell.btnPrice` or a different one?

Comment: cell.btnPrice shows text that is meant for another cell.  I know product A is on cell 10, for example.  I see btnPrice title being 10.25 then i scroll cell 10 out of view and then scroll it back into view and Kaboom it shows 23.45 or any of the prices for the other cells but sometimes it is still correct I need to scroll in out of view several times before I see wrong price on that cell

Comment: Does `self.order.customerRef` change at all? Look into that. Because `custPrice` is dependent on that.

Comment: self.order.customerRef changes when user select a different customer but when that happens I clear the products and prices and reload the whole table.  All my tests is with 1 customer so that cannot be the issue

Comment: Guess what guys!  it was nothing to do with what we thought, at least not what I thought.  If I replace btnPrice with a UILabel then everything is fine!  Put back to btnPrice and I get the issue I described.  I even created a very simple app with one view with a UITableView and made datasource a simple class with 2 properties.  No lenghty work or anything, the button still behaves badly.  I opened an Apple support question and waiting.  Thank you all for your help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the state of a cell is being reset in every `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call. You have a bunch of if/else conditions, and the control flow is such that the code for setting content on a cell isn't being called at all, which is why content from the previously reused cell remains.

My rule is to always have matching else conditions for `if`s where I change the state of the cell (if nothing then at least blank). In case of `UITableViewCell` subclasses, you can reset state in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: I commented both ifs - not really needed, they always eval to true

Comment: Still getting the issue after after removing the if
    if (prod != nil) {
and

Comment: if (self.order.orderOrderCustomer != nil) {

However, this line
          CustomerPrice *custPrice = [Common getPriceForCustomer:self.order.customerRef forProduct:prod.productId];

Comment: could take a few milliseconds and I am suspicious that is it that delay that is causing the issues and not reuse.  I added
    [cell.btnPrice setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
right after cell dequeue and made no difference

Comment: and apologies for the fragmented comments.  Every time I press enter it posts. I keep forgetting to do shift enter

Comment: -(void)prepareForReuse{
    [self.btnPrice setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

made no difference

Comment: I am going to try to put that slow method in background thread and see.  That is none can things of other solutions to try

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's better to use same identifier for all cells, if there are hundreds of records, so that cells can reuse memory. Otherwise, if the Tableview is long enough and the user scrolls fast through it, will cause a lot of allocs / deallocs, which will result on a not smooth scrolling. Then always put row specific code outside the condition which checks cell to be *nil*.

Take a look at this code snippet:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MY_CELL_IDENTIFIER";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        // Everything that is similar in all the cells should be defined here
        // like frames, background colors, label colors, indentation etc.
    }
    // everything that is row specific should go here
    // like image, label text, progress view progress etc.
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am using the same identifier for all cells.  Nil cell? I am checking.  I am using storyboard and the prototype cell is defined there.  As far as I know dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is guaranteed NOT to return nil in that setup